# Check if clicked element doesn't have a specific class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create an if statement that runs the code if the clicked li element doesn't have a class of photo.

```
$('div.menu li').click(function(){
    var content = $(this).attr('class');
    if (/* I can't figure out the correct syntax that goes here? */){
        $("div.content_wrapper, div.content").hide();
        $('div.content_wrapper').animate({width: 'toggle'});
        $('div.content_wrapper, div.' + content).show();
        $('div.menu li').removeClass('menuactive');
        $(this).addClass('menuactive');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`:not` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$("div.menu li:not(.photo)").click(function(){
    $("div.content_wrapper, div.content").hide();
    $("div.content_wrapper").animate({width: "toggle"});
    $("div.content_wrapper, div." + content).show();
    $("div.menu li").removeClass("menuactive");
    $(this).addClass("menuactive");
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Just use jQuery's `.is`:

```
if(!$(this).is('.some-class')) { // ...
```

Or, if you so prefer, `.hasClass`:

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('some-class')) { // ...
```

Comment: Use @EH_warch's answer instead, I didn't pay attention to the outer selector :)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(!$(this).hasClass('className')) {
    // clicked element does not have the class
}
```