# Unable to target button to separate behaviour using :not()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML5 application which has a table (ID is `#myTable` in the remainder of this question). The table is populated by an ajax request.

Following the ajax response a single row of the table looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>ID 001</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Baz</td>
    <td><a href="/fge?id=001" class="btn-fge">Find group entries</a></td>
</tr>
```

The anchor in the last column isn't present on every row. It only appears for certain rows. If the anchor doesn't appear an empty row is rendered: `<td></td>`.

Prior to this anchor being added I'd written a function which toggles expanding/collapsing each row. Upon expansion an additional ajax request was made to present further data. The behaviour was such that the user could click anywhere inside the row.

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function (e) { 
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');

    // Code to expand/collapse tr
    // ...

    // Ajax request for additional row data
    // ...
}
```

This all worked without any problems.

However, I want to segregate the behaviour such that the code above *doesn't* fire if the user has clicked the anchor. Conversely if they click anywhere inside the row other than the anchor it should fire.

I've read [Check if clicked element doesn't have a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278837/check-if-clicked-element-doesnt-have-a-specific-class/11278854) and attempted to target `.btn-fge` using a `:not()` condition as follows.

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td:not(.btn-fge)', function (e) {

}
```

This doesn't work (although I believe this might be because `.btn-fge` isn't a class on the `<td>` but rather an anchor inside it?). The collapsing/expanding row behaviour still fires followed by the browser redirecting to the `href` value. In the example given the behaviour is:

1. Click `.btn-fge`.
2. The row is expanded (or if it was already expanded it is collapsed).
3. The browser follows the `href` on `.btn-fge` so in this case redirects to `/fge?id=001`.

I want (1) followed by (3) to occur, but not (2) when clicking `.btn-fge`.

I've tried logging `console.log($(this));` followed by `e.preventDefault()`. It doesn't matter whereabouts inside the row I click - whether it's on the button or not - it gives the same output as follows.

[image]

How can I target this such that the button behaviour is different to clicking other places inside the row?

I'm using jquery version 3.2.1 and would prefer a jquery solution but a vanilla JavaScript one would also be acceptable.

Edit - I've made a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/adrq0nhz/ and if you click anywhere inside the table it will console log "this is still firing" which is effectively the issue of the anchor having no separate behavior. **Note: the `.btn-fge` class is on the anchor, not the `<td>`, and this cannot be changed.**

Comment: `td:not(.btn-fge)` targets all td's that don't have a class of `.btn-fge` - it works!

Comment: @Adam the class `.btn-fge` isn't on the `<td>`, it's on the anchor. If you run the fiddle I've linked to you'll see it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `target` property of the event object to check what element was clicked.

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
  //used prevent default for demonstration purposes to avoid the href link being opened.
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(e.target).is('a.btn-fge')) {
    console.log('clicked on anchor with the class btn-fge');
  } else {
    console.log('clicked outside of anchor with the class btn-fge');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>ID 001</td>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>Baz</td>
      <td><a href="/fge?id=001" class="btn-fge">Find group entries</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to Mark's method, you can also use the `.matches` method and pass it the class name you want to target.

```js
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('[class=btn-fge]')) {
    console.log('anchor clicked');
  } else {
    console.log('<td> clicked');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers all suggest checking this in the event handler, which, IMO, is in the wrong place.

The row-click event handler should only need to handle row click events, not that it should*n't* handle some other event.

This paradigm could get very messy very quickly with additional buttons/inputs/selects - better not to get into the handler in the first place.

You can stop the row getting the click with `e.stopPropagation()` - this allows you to still click in the same cell around the button, eg:

```js
$("table tr td").click(() => console.log("row click"));
$(".btn-fge").click((e) => e.stopPropagation());
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID 001</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Baz</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn-fge">Find group entries</a>click here also works</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ahn6dc1/

---

An alternative is to not add click to the button cell.  It's noted that you don't want to change the HTML, but you can still "change" the HTML via js, example:

```js
$(".btn-fge").closest("td").addClass("noclick");
$("table tr td:not(.noclick)").click(() => console.log("row click"));
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding:2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ID 001</td>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td>
    <td>Baz</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="btn-fge">Find group entries</a>click here does nothing</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jQuery's .find() method

```
$('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'td', function (e) {

    // proceed only if a child does not exist with class .btn-fge 
    if(!$(this).find('.btn-fge').length){

        // non-anchor td clicked
    }
}
```